# Drop timestamps when starting/looping again

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I've got a `df` that contains a time series of values. The timestamps run through to a certain point and then begin again. Because this end point can vary I have to manually find the end and then subset the desired output.

I'm hoping to find a more automated function to do this. Using the `df` below, the time series begins at `2020-04-13 19:25:34.1` and finishes at `2020-04-13 19:45:34.1`. So approx 20 mins. The time series then begins again at around that `2020-04-13 19:25:34` mark (it may not be to the exact 0.1 sec).

For reference the time series of my datasets will expand over 30-40 mins and then start again. But the start of the second loop may not necessarily begin at the same time point.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({   
        'Val' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2],             
        'Time' : ['2020-04-13 19:25:34.1','2020-04-13 19:25:34.1','2020-04-13 19:35:34.1','2020-04-13 19:35:34.1','2020-04-13 19:45:34.1','2020-04-13 19:45:34.1','2020-04-13 19:25:34.3','2020-04-13 19:25:34.3','2020-04-13 19:35:34.1','2020-04-13 19:35:34.1'],                 
    }) 

# Return first set of timestamps manually
df1 = df1[:6]
```

The main reason I'm doing this is because I need to perform a groupby later on. If I don't drop the second set of timestamps it get's sorted altogether, which is undesirable.

```
Val_group = df1.groupby(['Time'])['Val'].apply(list)

Time
2020-04-13 19:25:34.1          [1, 2]
2020-04-13 19:25:34.3          [7, 8]
2020-04-13 19:35:34.1    [3, 4, 1, 2]
2020-04-13 19:45:34.1          [5, 6]
```

In saying this, I think it will be cause less issues if I filter the first set of time points initially because I'd have to adjust a lot of backend code. So instead of subsetting manually, is there a more efficient method to filter the first set of timepoints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use the `datetime64[ns]` dtype which allows for math. Then form groups checking where the difference with the next row is negative. With the created `'grp'` indicator, you should be able to select whichever group you want (`df1[df1['grp'] == 1]`), or you can now use that as the grouping in later `groupby` operations.

```
df1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Time'])
df1['grp'] = df1['Time'].diff().dt.total_seconds().lt(0).cumsum()
```

---

```
print(df1)
   Val                    Time  grp
0    1 2020-04-13 19:25:34.100    0
1    2 2020-04-13 19:25:34.100    0
2    3 2020-04-13 19:35:34.100    0
3    4 2020-04-13 19:35:34.100    0
4    5 2020-04-13 19:45:34.100    0
5    6 2020-04-13 19:45:34.100    0
6    7 2020-04-13 19:25:34.300    1
7    8 2020-04-13 19:25:34.300    1
8    1 2020-04-13 19:35:34.100    1
9    2 2020-04-13 19:35:34.100    1
```

Comment: Thanks ALollz, my groupby methods are a little different. There's a few of them to so I think my first option of returning the first time series is ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Group and aggregate by minutes, seconds and microseconds. This way you won't have to filter it out. Add `df1['Time'].dt.hour` if you also need the hour.

```
df1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Time'])
df1.groupby([df1['Time'].dt.minute,df1['Time'].dt.second,df1['Time'].dt.microsecond]).count()

            　Val    Time
Time　Time　Time      
25  34  100000  2   2
        300000  2   2
35  34  100000  4   4
45  34  100000  2   2
```